# TypeError: bufsize must be an integer?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am making a small program where I can open a file from any part of the computer with it's default editor. This is my code:

```
from os import *
import subprocess
print("Welcome to my File Finder. Here you can search for a file and open it.")
file_name = str(input("Your file's name:"))
print(subprocess.call(["xdg-open"], file_name))]
```

But instead of opening, it return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Important_tester_projects.py", line 6, in <module>
  print(subprocess.call(["xdg-open"], file_name))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 609, in __init__
  raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

I have googled to find a solution for this error, but I can't find any that seems to solve my Problem. How can fix my error?

NOTE: My Linux OS uses XFCE, not Gnome.

Comment: This is a simple typo: instead of passing `["xdg-open", file_name]` as the args, you’re passing ["xdg-open"]` as the args and `file_name` as the bufsize.

Comment: @abarnert what should I pass then?

Comment: @mahir, he means use `call` like this `print(subprocess.call(["xdg-open"], file_name))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subprocess cp returns error - bufsize must be integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156193/subprocess-cp-returns-error-bufsize-must-be-integer)

Comment: @aydow it still returns error

Comment: Pass `["xdg-open", file_name]`, just as I said. I guess this isn't a simple typo, and you don't understand the API?

Comment: @aydow No I don't. That's exactly what he's already calling, so it's going to cause the exact same error he's already getting.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i meant `print(subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file_name]))`

Comment: @aydow Since that question is itself a dup of [bufsize must be an integer error while grepping a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824096/), probably better to use the latter as a dup target, unless there's something wrong with it. (I already voted to close as a typo and retracted, so I can't vote to close as a dup…)

Comment: @abarnert, i did see that, but i think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156193/subprocess-cp-returns-error-bufsize-must-be-integer better addresses this question.

Comment: @aydow OK, cool. If I hadn't wasted my vote, I'd vote for your dup. :)

Comment: @abarnert no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead, use `subprocess.check_output()`. Since your command has multiple words, parse your command with `split()` method from [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) lib.
Something like this:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd=shlex.split('[find][2] root_dir -name file_name')
print subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```