# I am trying to use subprocess function to run a certain tool in linux terminal. I have the complete syntax for running it in terminal but in program?

Tags: python, subprocess

After installing the tool onto the computer, if this line is typed, the program will run,
" ffuf -c -w /path/of/textfile/as/input -u some_argument "
Do help me in finding out how i can use subprocess to make this happen and display the final output provided to me by the program.
Thank you!

I have 0 knowledge on subprocess and I'm not able to sort out how i can use it to perform the action. Kindly help. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: This is a duplicate please refer to the following question to run your command and get the output. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3503909/11993925

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `subprocess` module in Python

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("fuf -c -w /path/of/textfile/as/input -u some_argument", shell=True)
```

#### Using `os`

```py
import os
os.popen('fuf -c -w /path/of/textfile/as/input -u some_argument').read()
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working. It is giving me an error, n __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: @shivaM Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156193/subprocess-cp-returns-error-bufsize-must-be-integer